# How to save input colors in awk?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I've seen many more or less related topics, but all I found discuss how to color `awk` output. I need to preserve the color that was provided as `awk` input. For example, now I have:

```
./some_command
(red_text) (blue_text) (green_text)

./some_command | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'
(red_text) # < but the color is standard terminal color, not red anymore
```

How to keep the original coloring in the `awk` output?

Comment: *"The reason is not that awk strips colours but rather that  "well-designed" programs that produce coloured output typically do so only when their output goes to a terminal, not when it's sent to a pipe or to a regular file. The reason is that data sent on a terminal is presumably read by a human, whereas data piped to a program or written to a file is likely to be parsed by some program, so it shouldn't contain extraneous content like colour-changing escape sequences."* https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185611/48232  - so you may need to force the original program to generate coloured output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some_command may have an option to force color even when it's
connected to a terminal, for example with grep it would be
`--color=always`. If it doesn't though you have to trick some_command
into thinking it's connected to a terminal. Using `script` for example:

```
script --return --quiet -c 'echo a b | grep --color a'   /dev/null | awk '{print $1}'
```

There would be no color if you ran grep without `script`:

```
echo a b | grep --color a  | awk '{print $1}'
```